# Azure Redis and Lua script to read/compare/write

Tags: azure, lua, redis, transactions

I have a very simple Use Case. 
I have several instances of Azure Logic Apps running in parallel, each Logic App calls an Azure function to determine if the current message needs to be processed or not.
The Azure function reads an entry in the Redis Cache and compares the value with the value coming from the message currently processed by the Logic App.

If the value from the message is greater than the value stored in the cache (or if the values does not exist in the cache), the value in the cache is overwritten and the function returns "true" to indicate that the message must be processed.

If the value in the cache is greater or equal to the value of the message, then the function returns "False" and the Logic App ignores the message.

Because I can have a lot of Logic App running in parallel I want to avoid the following situation: the Azure function read the value from the cache, then compare it and during the comparison, and another instance of the Azure function overwrite the value in the cache. And I don't want to limit the number of concurrent Azure functions running at the same time because I need to process a lot of messages in parallel.

In this use case, should I use "Lua" to do the read/comparison and write in a single and atomic transaction?

Comment: Yes, lua script is perfect for this use case.

Comment: Any samples for a get + compare + write operation?